# How to open a link targeted in an iframe in a new tab with the same layout and the iframe

Tags: html, iframe, anchor

When I click the link **home** on the page, the corresponding file opens up in the `iframe` shown by the arrow as it is targeted at it.

But, when I right click the link and click on **open link in new tab** then only the page corresponding to the link i.e the content of the `iframe`, opens up in the new tab and not whole layout.

What I want is that when I open that link in a new tab, the exactly same thing opens up in the new tab as shown in figure.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So basicly your problem is: you need to check if the `iframe` content is actually being open inside an `iframe`.

With [window.top](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_top.asp) you can achieve that.

After that, if you content is not being open inside an `iframe`, make it redirect to the main page.

This is a sample, but i guess you can adapt for what you want:

**home.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Main Page</title>
    <head>
    <body>
        <h1>Main Page</h1>
        <a href="page2.html" target="myIframe">Page 2</a>
        <iframe name="myIframe" src="page1.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

and **page2.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page 2</title>
        <script>
            if (window.top == window.self) {
                window.location.replace("mainpage.html");
            }
        </script>
    <head>
    <body>
        <h1>Page 2</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```